# PowerShell - Run script 5 minutes before set time

Tags: powershell, scripting

I'm looking to run a script when comparing 2 different time sets. The script should only run at the interval of 5 minutes before the set time.

```
Example:
$CurrentTime = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
$Time2 = "2020-10-05 13:20:00"
```

How do I write "Run script only if $CurrentTime is 5 minutes before the $Time2 ??? "

```
if($CurrentTime ??5min less than?? $Time2){
    Write-Host "Time match"
} else {
    Write-Host "Time does not match"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you `-format` the `Get-Date` cmdlet, the return value becomes a `String` and if you do not specify any formatting the return value is a `DateTime` object. Without formatting the output into a `String`, you can then perform some operations to the `DateTime` object such as addition or subtraction. Just be sure to create another `DateTime` object from the `String` you want to compare (In this case it is `$Time2`.).

```
$CurrentTime = Get-Date
$Time2 = Get-Date -Date "2020-10-05 13:20:00"
```

However, since `$CurrentTime` object holds information down to the millisecond level, it is rarely possible to compare this two objects with an `equals` operator. What I would do is that I would choose a comparison window such as 1 minute and then check whether those two objects are similar to each other by a 1 minute window. In this case, it can be like `$CurrentTime` is in the window of 5 or 6 minutes less than `$Time2`. Then the script should contain something like:

```
if($CurrentTime.AddMinutes(6) -gt $Time2 && $CurrentTime.AddMinutes(5) -lt $Time2){
    Write-Host "Time match"
    }else{
    Write-Host "Time does not match"
    }
```

You can narrow the window down to level of seconds and say something like the below instead.

```
if($CurrentTime.AddSeconds(360) -gt $Time2 && $CurrentTime.AddSeconds(330) -lt $Time2){
    Write-Host "Time match"
    }else{
    Write-Host "Time does not match"
    }
```

Let me know if this helps you!